# How to add column with default options using ENUM

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, check-constraints

I want to add one column in tables which is called category, but i try a couple of options and doesn't work

```
 alter table attachments
                add
                (
                  category varchar2(20) not null check (category in ('default','agreement','security','information') DEFAULT 'default')
                );
```

I also try something like this

```
 ALTER TABLE attachments
 ADD  category ENUM ('default','agreement','security','information') DEFAULT 'default'
```

I check a couple of post here but I can not find any solution. Where did I made mistake ? what is wrong here ?
I get message

```
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Comment: `ENUM` is MySQL syntax and is not valid in Oracle.

Comment: Yes, I just see documentation. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase this as:

```
alter table attachments
add category varchar2(20) 
    default 'default'
    check (category in ('default','agreement','security','information'))
    not null 
;
```

Comment: @xerror You should also name the constraints (that way you can tell what has failed rather than trying to decode a system-generated constraint name). Something like `... DEFAULT 'default' CONSTRAINT attachments__category__chk CHECK ( ... ) CONSTRAINT attachments__category__nn NOT NULL`.